# making div draggable oin the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers-3

I have jsfiddle as follows:

```
    map.addOverlay(new ol.Overlay({
    position: divLoc,
    element: $("<div/>").attr("id", "pt_" + cityName).attr("box", "#dv" + cityName).addClass(colV + " mapMarker markerActive").on("mousedown", function (e) {
        console.log("clicked maker");
        console.log(e);
        var targetObj = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        // not let boxes close
        if (targetObj == "td" || targetObj == "tr" || targetObj == "table" || targetObj == "th" || e.target.className.indexOf("mapDivs") > 0) {
            // load highcharts dont close box 
           // alert("load highchart data from here");
            return -1;

        }

        //  var box = $("#" + e.
        $($(this).attr("box")).toggle(); // this will show / hide box
        $(this).toggleClass("markerActive"); // this will apply style to marker 
        console.log($($(this).attr("box")));
    }).append($("<div/>").addClass("mapDivs row " + colV).attr("id", "dv" + cityName).append(boxTable).draggable())
}))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gawaliswapnil1/34g4c1c7/1/

I am trying to move the box,before adding the function draggable it's woking fine,
But now the css changes are not working.
any help would be appreciated.

Thanks